# Bar Graph in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a sequence in a column (approx. 4000 records) of a dataframe which is of this form:

```
     seq        Class
ACIIERKNRGELEYT        1    
CASQEFDYEFDDVNE       -1
CDLNENQTWVDNGC        -1
CDRKENACIIERKNR        1
DDDFQEIITDKD              -1
```

I need to develop a grouped bar chart (using seaborn) of the frequencies (%) of each letter in a sequence based on class. To be precise, how many
times each letter (in percentage) like 'A', 'C', 'I', etc. is present in the seq (it has to be differentiated based on classes i.e., 1 or -1). I did try few techniques that but I could get the expected result.

This is the code that I used:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(final_df['epit_seq']) 
for i in final_df['seq']:
    print(i,counts[i])
```

here `final_df['seq']` is the column of the dataframe that contains the sequence as mentioned in the question. I am getting the frequency of the whole sequence, but I need the freq of individual character of each seq.

Comment: If you show what you have tried then maybe someone can help you out but seriously, if you havent got any code then your chances of getting any help are close to zero.

Comment: edit your orginal question & put the code in there

Comment: How does the class affect the result? Do the sequences need to be grouped by class? And what is `final_df['epit_seq']`? You should add expected output to help clarify the requirements.

Comment: Final_df is the Data frame and epit_seq is the col name. Yes, the seq has to be grouped by class of  1 or -1